# I want to get the form data set in a pojo in my controller using spring 3, as like struts1.2 approach

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc, controller, get

I have login.jsp as my welcome page/home page. Like struts1.2 approach I want data from my login.jsp(username and password) to be set in a pojo(LoginForm) and I need to access username and password from pojo in my Controller.

**login.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring 3.2.1 MVC Series</title>
</head>
<body>
   <br><div align='center'> <h2>Welcome to Spring MCV 3.2 Example. </h2><br> </div>
   <br/>
   <form:form method="post" action="login.do" modelAttribute="req">
<label for="UserName :"></label> <form:input path="name"/>
<label for="Password :"/> <form:password path="password"/>
<input name="submit" type="submit"/>
   </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**LoginForm pojo class**

```
public class LoginForm {
private String name;
private String password;
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {      
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

**LoginController**

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import com.spring3.bean.LoginForm;
@Controller

@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView userLogin(@ModelAttribute("req") LoginForm login,BindingResult result)
{
    System.out.println("Inside LoginController...");
    return new ModelAndView("welcome","req",new LoginForm());
}
}
```

web.xml and dispatcher-servlet.xml file contains appropriate mappings.

I am getting the below error.

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean     name 'req' available as request attribute
"
```

My requiremnet is as in struts1.2 we get data in Action form from jsp same way how to do in spring 3, as it is a migration project.

Comment: Is the error happeneing prior to the System.out.println() or after?

Answer (score 0):

To get the form data set in a pojo in my controller  like struts1.2 or 2x
you need to use commons-beanutils.jar API

This API will be able to give you HTML form data in a bean, just include this jar along with commons-logging-1.1.jar ( required for logging ) in your build path

add the below util class to your project

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

/**
* @author count
* FormUtil class used BeanUtils class populate method for setting the form values in       Java beans.
*  I made this class a generic class so that we do not need to write same lines again and again in each servlet, 
*  just we need to pass the class of java bean and request in populate method of FormUtil. 
*/
public class FormUtil {

public static <T> T populate(Class<T> clazz, HttpServletRequest request) {
    T object = null;
    try {

        object = (T) clazz.newInstance();
        BeanUtils.populate(object, request.getParameterMap());

    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return object;
}
}
```

Now where you want the object of your POJO use the below code

```
 LoginForm loginForm = FormUtil.populate(LoginForm.class, request);
```